# How to get the room dimensions from a map build using gmapping?

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a map build using gmapping. It contains the PGM image and a yml file. This map is built for the tuttlebot3 house environment. Now, I want to get the size or the dimensions of each room in the house using the map.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355653/how-to-get-the-room-dimensions-from-a-map-build-using-gmapping?/) by [violator](https://answers.ros.org/users/56046/violator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Publish the map using map_server:

```
rosrun map_server map_server yourmap.yaml
```

Then use the "Measure" tool in rviz to measure the rooms.

---

Originally posted by [nsprague](https://answers.ros.org/users/2815/nsprague/) with karma: 228 on 2020-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1